# How to invoke an API from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a requirement where I want DynamoDB TTL to put data into DynamoStream (when expired) and then send it to a Lambda. And I am able to achieve this. Now anytime an item gets expired it acts as a trigger to my lambda and I can see the items in `console.log` of Lambda method by investigating the `event`.

**Question -** I want to do some processing based on the items that are expiring. And for that to happen I need to make an API call to certain end point passing information about the items. I searched alot on google and even checked Lambda `blueprints` but I could not find a basic example where data received by lambda is being sent to a REST End point. Can someone guide me with this. All I find on google is how to integrate API Gateway with lambda. I am a beginner so need some guidance here.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What is your programing environment?  Everything supported by Lambda should be able to make a simple HTTP call.

Comment: My backend code will be in .Net, but does it matter if I make the call from node.js (lambda) to my .net (C#) api? It's surprising that I don't find search results related to such a requirement.

Comment: Why send it from Lambda to an API endpoint? Why not make the Lambda function itself the endpoint, so implement whatever code you need there (in Lambda).

Comment: We have 10,000 of lines of processing that needs to be happening on the expired item. And entire code base is in .Net

Comment: OK, then I would recommend that your Lambda simply publish the data to SNS and then have SNS send it onwards to your HTTPS endpoint.

Comment: I need SNS now? Why can't I make a basic request post/get request from inside of lambda? I am a beginner can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple for a Node.js Lambda to call a REST API.  It doesn't matter what your backend is coded in as long as it follows basic REST patterns.  As an example, a very simple Node Lambda might look like:

```
var https = require('https');
       exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
       var params = {
                    host: "example.com",
                    path: "/api/v1/yourmethod"

                    };

  var req = https.request(params, function(res) {
    let data = '';
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log("DONE");
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });
   req.end();
 };
```

Obviously your code would contain a bit more as you have to process the DynamoDB event but this is the basics for a GET.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will give it a try and if I have further question will ping you here and will accept your answer accordingly.